# Overwrite black border on input[type=text] CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form. This form uses css `.error` to mark the invalid fields. I have the following code setup to style the input type text:

```
input[type=text] {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

but when a user doesn't fill out the form correctly, it will add `.error` to the form:

```
.error {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

The problem: `.error` doesn't overwrite the `input[type=text]`. The borders will stay black but in the source code, the `.error` does get added but gets ignored.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can increase the specificity of the selector by using:

```
input[type=text].error {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: That worked! I tried `input[type=text] .error` before but that didn't work. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You're welcome Willy. If you feel like it, you can press the tick below the score to mark the answer as accepted :)